# Unhandled promise rejection Error: "[IN:Parser] Could not instantiate tag for 'login': t.user is null" while login with linkedin javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, linkedin-api

I am trying login with linkedin javascript sdk. It gives me the below error:

***Unhandled promise rejection Error: "[IN:Parser] Could not instantiate tag for 'login': t.user is null"***

I have tried so many other references from google, but could not solve this. Here is my code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
   api_key: 81n4hu3u7jybix
   authorize: true
   onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
  function onLinkedInLoad() {
   IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
  }

  // Logout user
  function logout(){
    IN.User.logout(onLogout);
  }

  function onLogout(){
    console.log('Logout successfully');
  }

  // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
  function getProfileData() {

   IN.API.Profile("me").fields("first-name", "last-name", "email-address","picture-url").result(function (data) {

    var userdata = data.values[0];

   console.log(userdata);

  }).error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- LinkedIn signin button -->
  <script type="in/Login"></script>

  <table id='tableUser' style='display: none;'>
   <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td><span id='fullname'></span></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><span id='email'></span></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Profile image</td>
    <td><img src='' width='32' height='32' id='profile_photo'></td>
   </tr>

  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? Do you remember how? I've got the same trouble now.

Comment: I had a mistake creating app configurations. Then it solved.

Comment: You mean that you fixed some app settings from your linkedin account and then it started to work - am I right?

Comment: yes, it works then after.

Comment: anyone want to specify the configurations needed to be fixed?